# Apache Solr Class 'SolrClient' not found fatal error

Tags: php, apache, solr, configuration, classnotfoundexception

I am in the phase of Apache Solr configuration on WAMP server.
When I run this code on WAMP server the it is showing PHP fatal error,

Fatal error: Class 'SolrClient' not found in C:\wamp\www\Search Enginge\home.php on line 54

**Home.php**

```
<?php
include "bootstrap.php";

$options = array
(
        'hostname' => SOLR_SERVER_HOSTNAME,
        'login'    => SOLR_SERVER_USERNAME,
        'password' => SOLR_SERVER_PASSWORD,
        'port'     => SOLR_SERVER_PORT,
);

$client = new SolrClient($options);

$query = new SolrQuery();

$query->setQuery("*.*");

$query->addField('id')->addField('author')->addField('content_type')->addField('user')->addField('file_type');

$query->setFacet(true);

$query->addFacetField('content_type')->addFacetField('file_type');

$query_response = $client->query($query);

$response = $query_response->getResponse();

$array=(array)$response['facet_counts']['facet_fields']['file_type'];

?>
```

**Bootstrap.php**

```
<?php

/* Domain name of the Solr server */
define('SOLR_SERVER_HOSTNAME', 'localhost');

/* Whether or not to run in secure mode */
define('SOLR_SECURE', true);

/* HTTP Port to connection */
define('SOLR_SERVER_PORT', ((SOLR_SECURE) ? 8990 : 8990));

/* HTTP Basic Authentication Username */
define('SOLR_SERVER_USERNAME', 'admin');

/* HTTP Basic Authentication pasword */
define('SOLR_SERVER_PASSWORD', '');

/* HTTP connection timeout */
/* This is maximum time in seconds allowed for the http data transfer operation. Default value is 30 seconds */
define('SOLR_SERVER_TIMEOUT', 10);

/* File name to a PEM-formatted private key + private certificate (concatenated in that order) */
define('SOLR_SSL_CERT', 'certs/combo.pem');

/* File name to a PEM-formatted private certificate only */
define('SOLR_SSL_CERT_ONLY', 'certs/solr.crt');

/* File name to a PEM-formatted private key */
define('SOLR_SSL_KEY', 'certs/solr.key');

/* Password for PEM-formatted private key file */
define('SOLR_SSL_KEYPASSWORD', 'StrongAndSecurePassword');

/* Name of file holding one or more CA certificates to verify peer with*/
define('SOLR_SSL_CAINFO', 'certs/cacert.crt');

/* Name of directory holding multiple CA certificates to verify peer with */
define('SOLR_SSL_CAPATH', 'certs/');

?>
```

Comment: Have you installed the extensions that delivers the `SolrClient` class ?

Comment: I have copied php_solr.dll in C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.8\ext and enabled php_solr extension in php.ini

Comment: use these https://code.google.com/p/solr-php-client/downloads/list

Comment: How to install that?

Answer (score 0):

Simply install the solr-php client with pecl;

```
sudo pecl install solr
```

If this fails with an error, that is probably due to the php version you are using (7.*). Report this bug to this [forum](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=75631&thanks=6).

Then compile and build according to the instructions in [this](https://github.com/php/pecl-search_engine-solr/tree/744e32915d5989101267ed2c84a407c582dc6f31) github repository.

( If you are using a newer version of php (7.*) ignore the library "php5-curl" )

This worked for me.